# Rename existing programming language name in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to change the name of an existing programming language in Notepad++. How do I do this?

[image]

For example, I'd like to rename Python (or whatever else) to 'Some other name'.

Comment: Admittedly a guess, but you might have to edit this in the source code and compile a custom version of Notepad++ yourself. An alternative might be to simply create a custom User Defined Language with the name you want.

Comment: just to clarify.. u want to just chg the name.. or the language (definition) itself?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I just want to change the name. The language definition itself should remain unchanged.